# How to reduce RDS cost for Audit data on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So i am struggling with a use case where i am paying huge amount to aws rds .
Here are few things that is my requirement

1. So i have 12 TB of data currently in On prem Oracle data base and i need to migrate to AWS.
2. This 12 TB data is Audit data .
3. I am displaying this Audit data to my application UI within 2 seconds.
4. I have Inserts and Updates but no delete to this Audit data .
5. The query that we will running is select few records or select single records as well .
6. No join to this table while displaying to application UI.

Now if i move this Audit data to AWS RDS/Mysql then it will satisfy my use case but the price that we will be paying is huge 
Also Audit data keeps on Growing .

So to solve this problem i need some other suggestion if some one can provide .

One thing that case to my Minda is using S3 which can be cost effective but how to handle Insert and Update and 
even if we combine with Athena but select time is very very slow .

Second i though of snowflake but again we are not using this for analytics but just for faster disply.

Apart from this is there anything that can be implemented here .

Please help me with this so we can reduce the cost .

I am open for any implementation on AWS if it can be cost effective .

Few Update to clarify more ..
1. I can not certainly remove data from this 12 TB even older data is accessed frequently .
2. Cost of On prem is high but we are migrating to aws cloud full system so as part of this we have to migrate .
3. Retention is that we have have keep all the data forever really at least for now .

So recieved no Comment on Snowflake but how about Apache HUDI ?
AWS EMR has native support for apache HUDI which can basically do record level insert/update/delete on S3

So all Insert/Update/Delete will be done using HUDI and select will be using S3 SELECT ?

Comment: What is the cost of your current Oracle system (both software license and cost of storage equipment)? Which part of the RDS costs are of concern to you? Does _all_ the data need to be queried quickly, or can older data be queried more slowly? Feel free to edit your question and include this information.

Comment: What is the retention requirement for this AUDIT data?  How many months required?  What is the number of complete days stored in your 12 TB today?  Could the data be stored in 1 file for each calendar day to accomodate purge of data when the data is NN days old with ALTER DROP TABLE? Using INNODB? Using innodb_file_per_table=1?

Comment: S3 Select only operates on one file. If you wish to retrieve data from S3, consider using either Amazon Athena or Amazon Redshift Spectrum (but only if you are already using Redshift). Your best savings will come from pushing old data to S3, but it will mean slower queries. The up-side is that old data doesn't change, so it could be stored in S3 as a Parquet file, making it fast and efficient for querying with Amazon Athena.

Answer (score 1):

If your business requirement is to extract records from 12TB of data within 2 seconds, then you will definitely need to use a **database**.

While **Amazon Athena** is excellent for processing large datastores, it could only provide this type of speed if the data was stored in a compressed columnar format (eg Parquet) with highly-relevant partitioning. This is probably unlikely, but without knowing your data and how it is stored and accessed, I cannot say for certain.

Databases have two basic costs: **Compute and Storage**.

#### Storage Costs

You have 12TB of data, so the storage cost is fairly fixed. At $0.115/GB, that comes to $1380/month. 12TB is a LOT of data, so it's a reasonable price to pay if you need all of it to be accessible.

If some of the data is less-used, then it might be worthwhile to **split the data**, so that **older less-used data** is stored in Amazon S3 and queried via Amazon Athena, while **recent often-used data** is kept in the database. However, this is totally dependent on the data you store and typical access patterns.

#### Compute Costs

This cost is driven by the size of the database instance. The size needed will depend upon usage patterns. If only one person is querying the data every few minutes, it can be a small database server. If many people are simultaneously querying the data, then the database will need to be bigger.

#### Total Costs

You mention that you need to migrate to AWS, but you do not mention why the migration is needed. If it is to **reduce costs**, then you can also include the savings that will come from using a managed database, where backups and failover can be automatically provided.

If the migration is due to other factors (eg obtaining better performance), then cost might not be an important factor.

You might also want to consider **Amazon Redshift**, which is designed for large **data warehouses**. It has the ability to store data in S3 separate to the compute by using the new RA3 nodes. However, data warehouses do not like frequent data inserts since the data storage will be less-optimized. Therefore, only consider it if MySQL is not performing well enough.

Comment: I have updated my question but looks like i dont have any option other than RDS .I do have huge updates and Inserts for the table.Also data is growing very rapidly .

Comment: Also my data is stored month wise i can do month wise partition .I do have CLOB column for the rows as well .

Comment: Can Apache HUDI be usefull here